# Вывод текста напрямую в модель

Tags: webgl, javascript, html5, opengl

Есть холст с моделью, которая рисуется с помощью WebGL. Мне нужно вывести текст на этот канвас с моделью. В интернете распространен такой способ:

- Создаем невидимый канвас с обычным 2D-контекстом
- Выводим на него текст нужного шрифта и цвета с помощью `fillText, setFont, setFillStyle`
- Создаем текстуру с изображением из невидимого холста
- Отображаем её на основном (видимом) холсте (с WebGL-контекстом)

Вот подробное описание этого способа: [WebGL text using a Canvas Texture](http://www.spoonofdeath.com/delph/webgltext.html).

А есть ли способ выводить символы без использования невидимого холста? Может быть, как-то можно получить изображение символов заданного шрифта или еще как-то?

Comment: Может именно это вы и искали [тыц](http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/nehe43.htm), [тыц](http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/nehe13.htm)

PS: позвольте поинтересоватся вы под обверткой пишите или, все-таки передумали?

Comment: В первой статье описана библиотека (dll). Как же я смогу получить к ней доступ из JavaScript-кода?

Оберткой пользуюсь. Она оказалась совсем простой, как JOGL (обертка без доп.логики). Но иногда и дописываю свои native-методы.

Comment: Я пока без понятия что и как делать (с canvas 3d поигрался на уровне кубиков и т.д.), но использование 2d canas для рендеринга чего-то типа текста, небольших панелен и т.д. - довольо рсспостраненная практика...

Answer (score 1):

Можно рисовать все 3D в контексте GL, а текст выводить поверх средствами HTML5/CSS.